# MacBook Air Mid 2011: headphone plug makes weird noises

Tags: macbook-pro

If I turn a headphone plug around in the headphone jack, it makes really loud and weird creaking noises. I just want to make sure that my Macbook Air isn't the only one which does that.

I already had a close look into the jack, but nothing seems to be wrong with it.

Comment: Is the noise coming from the physical components, or is the noise heard in the headphones?

Comment: Oh, sorry that I wasn't clear about this: it comes from the physical components.

Comment: Its Coming From My 13" Air Late 2012 when the apple earbuds are plugged in but not with the others. MacBook Pro does same thing with Apple Earbuds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such sound coming from mine. Sorry to say this - but it sounds like you have a repair coming your way.

It might still just be the headphones though - have you tried with different sets??

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like possibly the Inductor for your audio rail has gone bad, if you are competent with electronics you could locate the inductor on your board, schematics are widely available, with a multimeter you can measure the inductance, if its simply your inductor that has gone bad its a easy fix, have you tried it with any other headphone?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Fortunately, the problem appears to have disappeared since I've asked the question. I've disassembled the MacBook several times, perhaps that somehow helped. Why do you suspect the inductor? How could it create these noises?

Comment: the inductor is used to filter out any interference, what you described sounds like interference, my first thought would be the inductor.